# SCSS file not compiling anymore

Tags: sass

Until yesterday Sass was working just fine, now, Sass doesn't compile my SCSS file anymore.

Here's what I've tried so far but nothing fixes the problem:

1. Uninstalling current version of Sass and installing an older version
2. Installing the latest version of Sass
3. Uninstalling Ruby and installing the latest version
4. Rebooting my machine

**Technical information:**

- Win7 64b
- Sass version 3.2.3
- Compass version 0.12.2
- CMD commands used: `sass --watch scss:css --style compact --compass --debug-info`
- Editor: Sublime Text 2

**Other information:**

Something weird that happens is that if I write something incorrect in my `.scss` file, for example a four digit hex value for a color like `#f00a` and then run `--watch`, Sass immediately detects the problem, and rewrites the `.css` file with the error.

This means that Sass is, in some way, partially working.

After typing all the `--watch` commands, Sass initiates normally saying: `>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.`

However, when I save my `.scss` file, Sass doesn't compile anymore. It just stays there.

Has anyone else had this issue where Sass just stops compiling?

Thing is that now I can't work on my projects anymore since there's no way to create CSS files anymore, so any help on this is immensely appreciated.

Thanks.

**--UPDATE**

I'm still not able to compile.

However, after stopping the `--watch` I get a huge list of items in my CMD. In my home PC Sass is working fine and when I stop the `--watch` I don't get any list like this one or anything:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\...\www>sass --watch scss:css --style compact --compass --debug-info --trace
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/util/multibyte_string_sc anner.rb:36:in `scan': Interrupt from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/util/multibyte_string_scanner.rb:36:in `scan'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1142:in `tok'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:865:in `value!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:845:in `declaration'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:568:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1090:in `block in catch_error'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1090:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1090:in `catch_error'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:567:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:540:in `block_child'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:532:in `block_contents'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:521:in `block'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:515:in `ruleset'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:539:in `block_child'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:532:in `block_contents'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:70:in `stylesheet'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:341:in `update_stylesheet'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:203:in `block in update_stylesheets'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:201:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:201:in `update_stylesheets'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:235:in `watch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/plugin.rb:107:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:444:in `watch_or_update'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:307:in `process_result'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/bin/sass:8:in `<top(required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/sass:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Is there something wrong with the CSS parser or something?

Comment: When I was using vanilla Sass, I never had a problem with `--watch` recompiling promptly.  Since I started using Compass, I started noticing what you're describing.  Adding extra dummy classes periodically seemed to help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "adding dummy classes"? But basically, how were you finally able to solve the problem? And how long ago did this happen to you? I'm trying to determine if this something with the new or older versions. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it isn't solved, it still happens now and then.  I started using Compass about a month ago.  I just add a `.test { border: 1px solid }` periodically if it isn't compiling and sometimes it helps, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Errors they reproduce by using the Compass instead of Sass? Try the following command: `compass watch --sass-dir scss --css-dir css -s compact --debug-info`

Comment: @piouPiouM Oh boy, did I wish your recommendation worked :( - but it didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem: One of the .scss files in my /scss folder was causing Sass to stop compiling.

The "problematic" file was an old copy of the project's main .scss file, but when I compared that old version with the latest version, I only see a handful of differences in terms of properties, values and a media query at the bottom of the code.

Other than that, both, the "problematic" and "correct/working" files are pretty much 98% exactly the same.

Read a more extensive answer in the project's issues list in GitHub: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/362#issuecomment-11255429

Comment: I don't know why but it seems whitespace can cause some problems. It shouldn't as SCSS is supposed to use brackets. I was getting errors like: 'Invalid CSS after "...ckground-color:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " $background_co..."'. Hard to prove as once I'd removed all the leading whitespace I couldn't get these errors back!!

Answer (score 20):

I experienced a similar issue, but using Sass with Compass. Luckily I managed to solve the problem by running the `compass clean` command which removes the `.sass-cache` files and the compiled .css files. Then just run the `compass --watch` command again. Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: This answer helped me figure it out, even though I'm not using Compass. I simply had to remove the .sass-cache hidden directory (i.e. "rm -r .sass-cache") and voila, sass is working again.

Comment: compass clean, then compass watch fixed the issue.  Thanks a ton guys this isn't the first time I have had this issue...Guess it would help if I read compass Docs :D

Comment: as @umesh did I removed the compiled .css, but also the map file.

Answer (score 8):

Admittedly this was **very stupid of me**, but it did happen to be the problem I had when stumbling upon this stackoverflow Q&A.

This was the simple answer to my very simple problem:

Make sure you're @importing the file in your main style.scss file.

Clearly not the answer to your very complex problem, but it may help some newbie who was in a similar position to me!

Comment: Yes, newbie here o/
Thanking you for this note that got my problem solved :) :P

Answer (score 0):

In every changes on your children scss files. You should save (ctrl+s) your main scss file.